# Duplicate top banners show different sentences

Tags: support, questions, duplicate-questions, closed-questions

I noticed that, when dealing with questions closed as a duplicate, the banner can show different sentences.

For exemple, let's consider those three questions closed a duplicate.

One can have this banner stating that "*This question is an exact duplicate of:*":

[image]

Another has this banner stating that "*This question already has an answer here:*":

[image]

And this last one has this banner, stating that "*Possible Duplicate:*":

[image]

For all of them, the following banner is shown at the bottom of the question (with different users, of course):

[image]

So I guess all these questions have been, in the same way, closed as a duplicate but why the top banners show different sentences?

Comment: I think they just keep whatever the text for the close reason was at the time they were closed.  So if it was closed before the rewording, it just keeps that in the banner.  I think if it's reopened and the reclosed then it will get the new wording (don't do that unnecessarily though).  If I'm not mistaken, now non-existent close reason (like "not a real question") also persist until removed.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Thanks! That's also what I thought. That the wording has been modified as time goes by and old question keeps the old wording (if this is what you meant).

Comment: Yep that's what I meant.  Although it would be nice for an SE developer/employee to confirm that this is the real behavior.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Sure, waiting for someone to confirm your premise.

Comment: @D4V1D unless I'm wrong, the revision history of a post will show you WHEN they are closed