# What to do with exact duplicate of question without answers

Tags: discussion

I just discovered two identical questions (except for the title and the indentation) by different users and both without any answers and was looking to mark one as a duplicate but apparently at least one of them must have an answer.

I've searched here but haven't found any info on identical questions by different users. What should I do in this case?

1. Write a comment on the duplicate with a link to the original.
2. Downvote one or both questions.
3. Flag or vote to close for another reason, e.g. flag as "in need of moderator intervention".
4. Ignore it.

Here are the questions:

[Get wrong filesize from base64 string in real android device ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66952874/get-wrong-filesize-from-base64-string-in-real-android-device-ionic)

[In ionic get wrong filesize from file base64 string in real android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66962657/in-ionic-get-wrong-filesize-from-file-base64-string-in-real-android-device)

Comment: They're _potentially_ identical enough to be automatically mod flagged, no harm in mod flagging yourself though

Comment: If you really care and want to go the extra mile, you can `follow` both of them, and once an answer is posted on any, you can mark the other as a duplicate. You can also post comments on both linking between them

Comment: I would raise a custom mod flag, as I suspect that the user whom posted the question posted the second to avoid a question ban. If they did, a mod/CM will likely delete the other account and question. If it isn't, then it'll still likely be marked as helpful, even if no action is taken.

Comment: Scratch my last comment; I missed that these are exact duplicates.

Comment: My thoughts on that the user is the *same* is also cemented by their profiles: *"javascript developer at biztechcs"* and *"javascript developer at Biztech ahmedabad"*. That is no a coincidence.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Based on them I think the best option would be for SO to add an "exact duplicate" option to close votes since there doesn't seem to be a clear answer as to how report them (the excluding the mod flag because it's not clear how detailed you have to be.

Comment: *"I think the best option would be for SO to add an "exact duplicate""* there is, it's just limited to when the user is also the same. [“This question already has answers here” vs “This question already exists”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403450/2029983) Users avoiding a question ban (which as I mentioned is what I strongly suspect is happening here) are a different problem altogether, and need mod attention.

Comment: @JeanneDark Thanks, there are a couple of very informative links in those answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this example I would raise a custom mod flag. This is also certainly a user using a second profile to post the same **exact** question (though note I have no conclusive proof of this). This is *normally* done when the other account the OP has used has a question ban and thus they are using a new account to avoid the ban; this is not allowed. More often the OP would also delete their old question, and then create a new one but not always.

In this scenario, this conclusion seems to be more cemented by the respective user profiles, where their job titles are: *"javascript developer at biztechcs"* and *"javascript developer at Biztech ahmedabad"*. I highly doubt that is a coincidence.

So raise a mod flag, and state something like the following:

> This question is an **exact** duplicate of [this question](Question Link). I cannot vote to close it as one, as neither have an answer that is upvoted, however, this appears to be the same user, who could be intentionally avoiding a question ban to re-ask their unanswered existing question.

It's really important you explain *why* you aren't using a normal flag/close vote here, as otherwise the mod *will* just decline the flag and tell you to use the tools you have available to you (said flag/close vote options).

If this is a user avoiding a Question Ban, then a Mod/CM will likely delete the duplicate question and may well delete one of the accounts or process a merge (In my experience with such scenarios they tend to delete the new account, but neither are "new" here).

*Note: If the 2 questions were posted by the same user, you would have been able to flag/vote to close as a duplicate of the other.*

Comment: What do you mean by "question ban"?
At first I also thought they might have been posted by the same person but it might just be two people working at the same company. I don't know about question bans but it's interesting that the question was first posted by a 3 month user with 1 rep and then by a 1 year user with 150 rep.

Comment: I literally mean what it says, @Thomas , the user is *banned* from asking questions. [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/2029983)

Comment: Then I don't understand why they would post the same question again **1 day later** with a different account if the original post isn't closed or deleted. Is there any advantage to this (except appearing a little higher in the chronological list)?

Comment: I literally cover that in the answer, @Thomas ... *"This is normally done when the other account the OP has used has a question ban and thus they are using a new account to avoid the ban; this is not allowed. More often the OP would also delete their old question, and then create a new one but not always."* The OP didn't get an answer, so they are posting the question again.

Comment: Or may be just habit combined with laziness - always create a new account to ask a question... Or maybe there are actually different people from the same company/school posting the same question... But it does not really change what moderation action (custom flag) to take in this case.